# It's possible to make a "Selfish Mining Atack" on EOS Blockchain?

Tags: block-producer, blockchains, dpos, bitcoin

" **Selfish mining attacks** occur when an individual in a mining pool attempts to withhold a successfully validated block from being broadcast to the rest of the mining pool network. After the selfish miner withholds their successfully mined block from the group, they continue to mine the next block, resulting in the selfish miner having demonstrated more proof-of-work compared to other miners in the mining pool. This allows the selfish miner to claim the block rewards (and financial rewards) while the rest of the network adopts their block solutions"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike other blockchains having POW consensus, in EOS with DPOS (Delegated Proof-of-Stake), block production schedule is determined by the number of votes. Selfish mining has no meaning because the number of blocks that one block producer can generate is fixed by its schedule.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Proof-of-Work (POW) Mining in EOSIO which uses on Delegated Proof of Stake (dPOS) consensus algorithm.